# How to hide certain value inside text-box if checked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, textbox

There have data field inside textbox like

```
Description of goods: 1 X 40 HQ STC
                       4500 CTNS OF
                       VERMICELLI
```

Also, have checkbox label as "Add Contr STC".

My question is how can be done if, I checked the checkbox, then a value of `1 X 40 HQ STC`could be hidden from `Description of goods`field?

What's the solution for this problem?

Comment: Depends whether the string value '1 X 40 HQ STC' will always be the same

Comment: If not you'll need to split the string up into 2 parts, then hide and show the first part depending on the checkbox

Comment: @DNKROZ it not same value, it retrieve from database which is save by user

Comment: Ok so split the string into 2, you need a way of uniquely identifying the first part

Comment: @DNKROZ is there have any reference that I can refer?

Comment: Well for example, does it always start with a 1 and end with STC? Is it always 9 chars long (no whitespace)? Does the first part pull from a different datasource or is the whole description from the same place? You need to think of things like that